# Dropdown not responding on all pages

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I am attempting to include a dropdown menu on the nav-bar of this website (http://thrivematching.com/)

The login dropdown is working on the homepage, but when you navigate to other pages, it is not responding! Can anybody help me solve this issue? I am using the same code on other pages as I am on the homepage.

***Apologies:*** stackOverflow is displaying my code weird. So if you can inspect the page in your browser, that would be great.

Comment: if you could copy your code to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) then it will be more easy to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This drop-down uses a js file called `thrive.js`, and this file doesn't exists in the other pages, adding this file may fix the problem.

For example:  `<script src="javascript/thrive.js" data-minify="1"></script>`

Comment: YES! Thank you – seems as if the person who took this after me snuck in a new script file. Much appreciated